# How to handle return errors in solidity view functions?

Tags: solidity

I have contract, which use another contract, which receives a pair of tokens, and returns the best price by comparing several exchanges.

Problem is if such tokens pair is not on the contract exchanges list, the contract returns an error.

I need just something like this for solidity 0.4.24, for a view function (not send)

```
try{
  // get return from contract A
}catch{
  // get return from contract B
}
```

Comment: Try catch mechanism is introduced in solidity version 0.6.0, https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/control-structures.html#try-catch

Comment: Yes I know, but I asked about 0.4.24

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with abi.encodeWithSelector()